# Connecting to external computer with lidgren

Tags: c#, networking

I'm new to networking and thought i'd muck around a bit with lidgren before i start implementing it in my games, so i made a little client/server chat program that works fine on localhost and lan. I can connect other computers on my subnet and chat, but when it comes to connecting a friends computer not connected on my home network it becomes a bit tricky. I set up UPnP and port forwarding on the server application and i connect the client directly using my external IP address, but the problem seems to come from connecting my client with my external IP address as they never actually connect.

```
        Network.config = new NetPeerConfiguration("SKGCHAT");
        Network.config.EnableMessageType(NetIncomingMessageType.DiscoveryResponse);
        Network.client = new NetClient(Network.config);
        Network.client.Start();
        Network.outMsg = Network.client.CreateMessage();
        Network.outMsg.Write("password");
        Network.client.Connect("121.217.195.105", 14242, Network.outMsg); //doesnt work
        //Network.client.Connect("192.168.0.14", 14242, Network.outMsg); works
        //Network.client.DiscoverLocalPeers(14242); works
```

This is the client initialisation

```
        Network.config = new NetPeerConfiguration("SKGCHAT");
        Network.config.Port = 14242;
        Network.config.EnableUPnP = true;
        Network.config.EnableMessageType(NetIncomingMessageType.DiscoveryRequest);
        Network.config.EnableMessageType(NetIncomingMessageType.ConnectionApproval);
        Network.server = new NetServer(Network.config);
        Network.server.Start();
        Network.server.UPnP.ForwardPort(14242, "SKG Chat bb");
```

and this is the server initialisation

This following code should display a message to the server if it even receives the clients connection attempt but when run, no connection attempts are received.

```
 case NetIncomingMessageType.ConnectionApproval: //wan
                    string message = incMsg.ReadString();
                    outMsg = server.CreateMessage();
                    outMsg.Write("You've been received");
                    server.SendUnconnectedMessage(outMsg, incMsg.SenderEndPoint);
                    if (message == "password")
                    {
                        incMsg.SenderConnection.Approve();
                        finalMsg = "New Connection";
                        readDiag = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        incMsg.SenderConnection.Deny();
                        finalMsg = "Connection denied";
                        readDiag = true;
                    }
                    break;
```

I honestly am lost when it comes to networking and have no clue why it isnt connecting. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Solved it a while back but thought I'd post what I did to fix this issue, so I put in a few breakpoints on the ForwardPort method and it turns out it was returning false, meaning it was not forwarding the port, there was a bug in the lidgren library in the NetUPnP class method ForwardPort, but I couldn't see any obvious flaws in the lidgren code so I just put the ForwardPort method in a while loop to continuously attempt to forward the port, I also found that the forward port method worked on the second attempt 99% of the time, I don't know why it's not working on the first attempt though.